# htaccess - RewriteRule for static files

Tags: .htaccess

how to rewrite urls for images and other static files to specific folder, i.e. I am using this so far:

```
RewriteRule \.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt)$ /MyFolder/$1
```

but its not working,

please help.

------------------- update ---------------------

ok so now I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exmpale.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exmpale.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt))$ /exmpale.com/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exmpale.com$
RewriteRule !\.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt)$ /exmpale.com/index.php
```

so images redirected to exmpale folders work but now I would like to rewrite everything else to index.php, above solution is not working so far.

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt))$ /MyFolder/$1
```

or perhaps this:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*\.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt))$ /MyFolder/$1
```

If neither of those is what you're looking for please add details with some examples of your desired inputs/outputs.

As for your update, you probably want to use the `L` flag to stop rule processing when this rule matches. eg:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exmpale.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exmpale.com/

# The next line is long. Scroll to the end!
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt))$ /exmpale.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exmpale.com$
RewriteRule .* /exmpale.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not capturing the initial request. Try the following:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt)$ /MyFolder/$1.$2
```

This will get anything that ends in the extension specified and redirect under `/MyFolder/` For example: `/something/image.jpg` will now go to `/MyFolder/something/image.jpg`

**Note:** There may be better ways to do this by adding conditions to check for file type.